# How to avoid Reload on property set

Tags: c#-4.0, custom-controls

```
public bool ShowButton
    {
        get
        {
            return _ShowButton;
        }
        set
        {
            _ShowButton = value;
            ReloadGrid();
        }
    }


    public bool ShowText
    {
       get
        {
            return _ShowText;
        }
        set
        {
            _ShowText = value;
            ReloadGrid();
        }
    }


    private void ReloadGrid()
    {
         Gridview.Data ......
    }
```

When ever am setting those two proprities i need to call ReloadGrid. But my requirement is if i assigned the 2 properties also ReloadGrid should call only one time now its happening twice. How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to avoid this ?

By not calling `ReloadGrid` in the setter of the properties.

```
public bool ShowButton { get; set; }
public bool ShowText { get; set; }
```

You have to call it manually:

```
ShowButton = true;
ShowText = false;
ReloadGrid();
```

The other option is more difficult. You need a `bool` variable to store if it's already loaded and you have to set it to `false` in events where the data needs to be refreshed. Then you can check this variable in  `ReloadGrid`:

```
private bool GridNeedsReload { get; set; }
private void ReloadGrid()
{
    if(GridNeedsReload)
    {
        Gridview.Data ......
    }
}
```

Comment: `ShowButton = true;
ShowText = false;
ReloadGrid();`  <br/> Is not possible because ReloadGrid is private...   <br/> if i assign ShowButton = true .. ReloadGrid() will occur and ShowText = true here also i need the same ..   <br/> What exactly i want is like on final property set i need to Reload the grid